# How to Convert PDT Time string to DateTime

Tags: c#

I have the data in string format
"22:48:32 Jul 29, 2011 PDT"
Now I want to convert it into datetime.
How can I do it.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? Please post your code and explain what problems you are having with it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse DateTime with timezone of form PST/CEST/UTC/etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241789/parse-datetime-with-timezone-of-form-pst-cest-utc-etc)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably after this method:
[DateTime.Parse(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx)

PDT is -7 from GMT, so you can refer to the GMT and subtract 7 hours.

```
DateTime datetime = DateTime.Parse("Jul 29 2011 22:48:32 GMT"); // notice GMT
datetime = datetime.AddHours(-7); // minus 7 hours
```

Comment: On the fly its nice ones.