# How to convert this 05:41:33 Apr 23, 2012 PDT value to datetime in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse DateTime with timezone of form PST/CEST/UTC/etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241789/parse-datetime-with-timezone-of-form-pst-cest-utc-etc)
>   [How to Convert PDT Time string to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941839/how-to-convert-pdt-time-string-to-datetime)

I want to convert this value 05:41:33 Apr 23, 2012 PDT to datetime .

i am trying this but it is giving an error.

```
 DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("05:41:33 Apr 23, 2012 PDT");
```

Please help me guys how we can do it in C#.

Thanks,Rajbir

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `PDT` is not recognizable as a timezone by *any* of the parsing options for a `DateTime` in the BCL.

If you convert it to `-0700` before parse it will parse ok.

```
string correctedTZ = "05:41:33 Apr 23, 2012 PDT".Replace("PDT", "-0700");
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(correctedTZ);
```

Comment: @DorCohen you got the answer from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941839/how-to-convert-pdt-time-string-to-datetime. Do you think is this ok?

Comment: Oded thanks for your help but it has one issue. It is not giving the correct time. The dt has value 4/23/2012 6:11:33 PM. Can you please sort out it .

Comment: @RajbirSingh - No, I can't. It depends on what timezone the computer is on. On my computer I get "23/04/2012 13:41:33". What do you think the "correct time" should be?

Comment: it's ok. Anyways thanks Oded.