# The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime, There is an unknown word starting at index 25

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I am grabbing a pubDate node from a xml file,
Item.PubDate have the date that I grabbed.

NewsItem.Date is my datetime column in my database table column.

But I cant seem to parse it to datetime.

I get `"The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime, There is an unknown word starting at index 25"`

Item.Pubdate have this value: "Thu, 9 May 2013 05:04:18 PDT"

When I try:

```
NewsItem.Date = DateTime.Parse(item.PubDate);
```

I get that error.

How come with other xml files that pubDates it works?

and they have "Thu, 09 May 2013 09:15:11 GMT"?

Comment: Is PDT a recognized timezone?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241789/parse-datetime-with-timezone-of-form-pst-cest-utc-etc

Comment: You should reject XML files like that, timezone abbreviations are hopelessly ambiguous.  There are three distinct "CST" timezones for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string contains `PDT` (Timezone info), You can't parse with that in your string replace that with empty string and then parse.

```
NewsItem.Date = DateTime.Parse(item.PubDate.Replace(" PDT",""));
```

If the string contains GMT then

[DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fw7727c.aspx)

> s contains the Z or GMT time zone designator, and styles includes the RoundtripKind flag. The date and time are interpreted as UTC.

Answer (score 0):

The PDT is not recognised by DateTime.Parse() or Convert.ToDateTime(). But GMT is recognised which is why your second one works.

You need to specify the value that PDT represents.

See answer here. 
[How to convert this 05:41:33 Apr 23, 2012 PDT value to datetime in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296837/how-to-convert-this-054133-apr-23-2012-pdt-value-to-datetime-in-c)