# Why does this DateTime parse always fail?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, datetime, .net-4.0

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?  The `Assert.IsTrue(parses)` always fails.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Can_Parse_To_DateTime()
    {
        DateTime expected = new DateTime(2011, 10, 19, 16, 01, 59);
        DateTime actual;

        string value = "Wed Oct 19 16:01:59 PDT 2011";
        string  mask = "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss xxx YYYY";

        bool parses = DateTime.TryParseExact(value, mask, 
                                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                             DateTimeStyles.None, 
                                             out actual);

        Assert.IsTrue(parses);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
```

I have also tried it thus, with the same result:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void parsing()
    {
        DateTime expected = new DateTime(2011, 10, 19, 16, 01, 59);
        DateTime actual;

        string value = "Wed Oct 19 16:01:59 PDT 2011";
        string  mask = "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss YYYY"; // note removal of "xxx "

        value = value.Remove(20, 4);  // removal of the "PDT "
        bool parses = DateTime.TryParseExact(value, mask, 
                                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                             DateTimeStyles.None, 
                                             out actual);

        Assert.IsTrue(parses);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
```

Comment: The year should be "yyyy" (lower case), but I'm not sure there's any format string that will interpret "PDT".

Comment: @MattHamilton - that's the answer! changed it and it works.  Post as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Let @Al have the rep. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by Matt Hamilton, `yyyy` must be lowercase. And `xxx` is totally invalid. You can always test your format string using reverse method `DateTime.ToString(format,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`.

Comment: According to this previous question you can replace timezone string with timezone offset and it will work - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241789/parse-datetime-with-timezone-of-form-pst-cest-utc-etc

Comment: Really like that you gave the option to try a reverse check. It hadn't occurred to me when I had similar pains. Still not a total fix for the OP, but a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

```
 string mask = "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss PDT yyyy";
```