# Parsing a date time from an xml document with timezone abbreviations (e.g. CET )

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I rarely parse xml files and when I try to use the features integrated in Linq2Xml. However today I stumbled upon a date format I am not able to cast via:

```
XElement element = ...
var date = (DateTime)element;
```

The date is in the following format:

```
01/28/2009 02:31:54 CET
```

I already tried to parse the date using `TryParse` in various combinations, cultures, but whatever format I try the datetime parser complains about the space at position 20. Is there a way to parse this date without splitting the string or doing awkward things?

Comment: If the space is the problem, why not remove it before parsing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the timezone abbreviations (e.g. CET) aren't recognized.  Do you know the offset?

This person is having a related problem:
[Parse DateTime with time zone of form PST/CEST/UTC/etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241789/parse-datetime-with-timezone-of-form-pst-cest-utc-etc)

An example from his post:

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact("24-okt-08 21:09:06 CEST".Replace("CEST", "+2"), "dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss z", culture);
```

Obviously your date time format is a bit different, but it's an idea to bail you out.

If you can, ask the person giving you the XML to generate the date/times with ISO 8601 format to avoid custom parsing.

Comment: +1 The system is a large black box, no chance to change that.  Maintaining a dictionary of all possible timezone abbreviations, sounds promising :-).