# C# DateTime.TryParseExact getting the timezone wrong

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, tryparse

I'm trying to parse a date time string which contains some timezone information (May 1st 2014 9:45pm in EST timezone):

```
DateTime RecordedDateTime;
string fixedRecordedDateTime = "Thu May 01 21:45:00 +0500 2014";
string[] dateFormats = { "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy" , "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss K yyyy" };
DateTime.TryParseExact(fixedRecordedDateTime, dateFormats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out RecordedDateTime);
```

The DateTime object gets 5/1/2014 12:45 PM Local time (I'm in EST)

if I use (May 1st 2014 9:45pm in PST timezone):

```
string fixedRecordedDateTime = "Thu May 01 21:45:00 +0800 2014";
```

The DateTime object gets 5/1/2014 09:45 AM Local time

I don't understand what's going wrong, why am I not able to correct local time after giving the timezone information information.

I'm trying to use DateTime instead of DateTimeOffset, is there anyway to get this parsed correctly?

Comment: EST is GMT-5. PST is GMT-8. GMT+5 is <strike>India</strike>Pakistan, GMT+8 is China.

Comment: As a side note, check out [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/).

Comment: @AntonTykhyy GMT+5.30 is India, not GMT+5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string fixedRecordedDateTime = "Thu May 01 21:45:00 +0500 2014";`

This is 21:45 in UTC+0500. That would be 16:45 in UTC, or 12:45 in EDT (UTC-0400). I think you got your + and - reversed in the offset.

Comment: Thanks, I guess this post also needs to be corrected, I converted EST PST etc to a number using the code on the page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881819/c-sharp-tryparseexact-reading-time-zone