# Is there a way to convert this kind of string into a date?

Tags: c#

Trying to convert a string like this `Dec 1, 2016  1:48 PM CST` into a DateTime object.

`Convert.ToDateTime(story.AddedDateString);` Didn't work, nor did I really expect it to.

> System.FormatException: The string was not recognized as a valid
>   DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 21.

is the error message I get. Wondering if I can tell it the format before trying to convert?

Comment: Consider searching for keywords like **parse**. Because that sounds like what you're trying to do. Parse a string into a DateTime object, and provide a custom format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) will get you most of the way there.  For example:

```
string input = "Dec 1, 2016  1:48 PM";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "MMM d, yyyy  h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

However, it does not handle the time zone via an abbreviation, as there are [multiple time zones with CST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22868721/65358) as an abbreviation.  Conversion of "CST" to an offset is not supported directly within the framework.

If you convert to a format which includes the offset, you can convert it:

```
string input = "Dec 1, 2016  1:48 PM -06:00";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "MMM d, yyyy  h:mm tt K", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DateTime.ParseExact()` and specify a format string using the DateTime formatters available.

As an example:

```
string date = "Dec 1, 2016  1:48 PM CST";
DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(myDate, "MMM d, yyyy h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The only problem with this is that it won't handle your timezone. You'd have to handle the timezone by either replacing that portion of the string with a UTC offset (which `DateTime.ParseExact()` WILL handle if you use the format `zzz` which looks like `-06:00`) or removing that portion of the string and accounting for the timezone after you have an actual date object.

You can read more at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Comment: This would be an answer if you showed how it works.