# Convert custom DateTime string to DateTime object

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a DateTime from a custom string however I am getting the error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("Thu Feb 23 23:36:01 EST 2017", "ddd MMM dd hh:mm:ss K yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Any suggestions on where I am going wrong?

Comment: This question is not related to the duplicate that is proposed here. The problem is a different one.

Comment: @StephenReindl It's partially a duplicate, due to the improper timezone handling.

Comment: See the answer below the problem is related to the Hours (HH vs. hh) field, not the timezone...

Comment: @StephenReindl, besides the `HH` error, the main problem is that you can't parse a string containing `EST`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hh` is for a 12 hour clock. You should use `HH` for a 24 hour clock. You'll also need to see the [mentioned duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241789/parse-datetime-with-time-zone-of-form-pst-cest-utc-etc) for better timezone handling.

When in doubt about parsing custom formats, check the documentation! See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: So it appears that I can't use K for the EST.  This is how they are sending me the date string.  I will have to manipulate it some prior to converting it.

Comment: Thanks on the HH catch.  I didn't even noticed I had the wrong format there.

Comment: @JDS I know it may not be under control, but if you can avoid the need to parse timezone abbreviations like `EST` that would be ideal.