# C# Convert string to date time '2017-08-18 06:00:00 IST' to 'Fri 28th Jul 2017 / 06:00:00 IST'

Tags: c#

I have DateTime format string '2017-08-18 06:00:00 IST'  i want to convert to  'Fri 18th Aug 2017 / 06:00:00 IST'

please help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aside from anything else, it's unclear whether you're really starting with a string or a `DateTime`. A [mcve] would have helped here, along with how far you've already got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Converting a `DateTime` to `String`

I'm not clear exactly on if you are intending to do `string --> DateTime --> string`... But the following solution will do the `DateTime` to `string`, and gets you the desired output:

```
// set a date in UTC format
DateTime dateUtc = new DateTime(2017, 08, 18, 06, 00, 00).ToUniversalTime();

// convert the UTC date to the IST time zone
DateTime dateIST = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(dateUtc, "UTC", "India Standard Time");
string timeZoneText = "IST";

// the string you want
string result = String.Format("{0:ddd d}{1} {0:MMM yyyy / HH:mm:ss} {2}", dateIST,
    (DateTime.Now.Day % 10 == 1 && DateTime.Now.Day != 11) ? "st"
    : (DateTime.Now.Day % 10 == 2 && DateTime.Now.Day != 12) ? "nd"
    : (DateTime.Now.Day % 10 == 3 && DateTime.Now.Day != 13) ? "rd"
    : "th", timeZoneText);
```

The key here is the string format

```
{0:ddd d}{1} {0:MMM yyyy / HH:mm:ss} {2}

// 0 = DateTime (converted to your time zone, ex: IST)
// 1 = the "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "#th"
// 2 = "IST"
```

This will result in: **Fri 18th Aug 2017 / 06:00:00 IST**

Comment: This will only work with IST zone specifically, right?

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko no- it's generic

Comment: IST is "Indian Standard Time", it's _not_ "first". Therefore, your code is not generic, sorry

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko what do you mean by "first"?

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko did you try the code? I'm not sure you understood what it accomplished

Comment: Your code will not work with strings that have arbitrary timezone suffixes.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko - you could put any suffix by editing the string, and what did you mean with "first"?

Comment: but how will i convert  '2017-08-18 06:00:00 IST' to DateTime

Comment: @HarshalBhagat -- I thought that the OP meant how to create a **string format** from a `DateTime`. Not `string` to `string`.

Comment: @HarshalBhagat there's no easy way to achieve what you want without using external libraries. (In case your input will have various timezone suffixes): https://stackoverflow.com/a/241885/482868

Comment: @Svek do you realize Harshal Bhagat **IS** the OP?!

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko -- I just noticed that, but why did he accept this answer then? I'm confused... Haha... I think I'll move on to something else... Please downvote if you want me to delete this