# Convert String To Datetime e.g. "10/1/19 4:19:38 AM UTC"

Tags: c#, datetime, type-conversion

I need to convert this string to DateTime: `"10/1/19 4:19:38 AM UTC"`

I have tried the below and get various errors.

```cs
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
DateTime.ParseExact(value.ToString(), "MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss tt KKK", provider);
DateTime.ParseExact(value.ToString(), "MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss t K", provider)
```

this is different from [Parse DateTime with time zone of form PST/CEST/UTC/etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241789/parse-datetime-with-time-zone-of-form-pst-cest-utc-etc) as it is parsing an alpha month name

Comment: use only one d for day and one h for hour.  When you use one it will accept either one or two digits.  When you use two it will only accept two.

Comment: You are using the double digit format on the day and hour.

Comment: You can't parse this because "UTC" is not recognized as a valid parameter.

Comment: To echo Mitulat - you'll need to either strip off the UTC or convert it to a time zone (e.g. `"+00:00"`)

Comment: `"MM/d/yy h:mm:ss tt UTC"` or `"MM/d/yy h:mm:ss tt 'UTC'"` will parse as long as UTC is always in the string

Answer (score 1):

"UTC" is something that can't be parsed. You should use e.g. "+02:00" as a time zone indicator.

Remove the "UTC" from the end, after that go with this format:

```
"M/d/yy h:m:s tt".
```

Or change "UTC" to "+02:00" and use this format:

```
"M/d/yy h:m:s tt K"
```

Comment: Z can probably be parsed