# In .NET Core C#, how do I parse this Date string: 'Jun 3, 2021 4:36:56 PM EDT'

Tags: c#, .net-5

In .NET Core C#, how do I parse this Date string: 'Jun 3, 2021 4:36:56 PM EDT'

Tried this with Culture en-US, and it does not work:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("Jun 3, 2021 4:36:56 PM EDT", "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt K", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Thanks, Jim

Comment: What do you mean by 'parse'? What are you trying to get/end up with? Could it be on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) page?

Answer (score -1):

I believe there's no support for TZ abbreviations of that sort, they are generally a mess. You could fix it by replacing "EDT" with "-04", though, something like:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("Jun 3, 2021 4:36:56 PM EDT".Replace("EDT", "-04"), "MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt zz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I also changed your `dd` to `d`, and `hh` to `h`. You can refer to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) for more info on custom date/time formats. Also, [here's a relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/241789/10713658) with some alternatives.