# Need to convert simpledateformat(EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy) to DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I am receiving the API responses and doing some logic.

I am trying to convert a string to DateTime but I am unable to convert it in C#. I tried multiple ways but I am getting string in invalid format.

I need to convert "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy" to an equivalent DateTime format in C#.

I have two dates as below and need to calculate the total days from the two dates

var dt1="Wed Jul 14 07:59:30 BST 2021";
var dt2="Fri Jul 16 08:59:30 BST 2021";

Please give me any suggestions.

Comment: Welcome on SO  For your next question, please use the search function. There are already many questions like this on SO. Also provide a small snippet of your current code. Furthermore, [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=net-5.0) is very exhaustive when it comes to parsing

Comment: There is no built-in way to parse the time zone when written like that. Are your dates always "BST", or could the dates contain other time zones?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse DateTime with time zone of form PST/CEST/UTC/etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241789/parse-datetime-with-time-zone-of-form-pst-cest-utc-etc)

Comment: If you have any say in what that API provides, ask for either Offset instead of TimeZone if it has to be human readable or something like Unix Timestamp if not.

Comment: Hi Matthew , I am getting BST and GMT as of now. I will get any format in the future. It could be helpful if share some custom method to convert it to equivalent DateTime format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you need:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        String yourDate = "Wed Jul 14 07:59:30 BST 2021";
        DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact( yourDate,"ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'BST' yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString());
    }
}
```

It will give you this output: `7/14/2021 7:59:30 AM`