# C# Convert a string "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss 'UTC'" to date time

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime

I have a string, as an example: `"2022-04-17 14:46:31 UTC"`

And I want to convert it to date time but I have got the following error:

> The string '2022-04-17 14:46:31 UTC' was not recognized as a valid
> DateTime.There is an unknown word starting at index '20'."

Notice that I have tried:

```
var date =  DateTime.Parse("2022-04-17 14:46:31 UTC");
```

and

```
DateTime dt;
DateTime.TryParseExact("2022-04-17 14:46:31 UTC", 
                       "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss 'UTC'", 
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt)
```

Comment: `hh` is for 12-hour hour-of-day. You want `HH`.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have tried... does not work

Comment: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss 'UTC'`, note `HH`

Comment: Same issue... @DmitryBychenko: "The string '2022-04-17 14:46:31 UTC' was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index '20'."

Comment: DateTime.TryParseExact("2022-04-17 14:46:31 UTC", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss UTC", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt); Main things to note are that I removed the quote marks around 'UTC' and updated it to HH instead of hh

Comment: The exact code you've posted for item 2, just changing hh to HH, works fine for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things to be done:

1. as mentioned in the comments: use `HH` for the 24 hour format
2. adjust the result to an actual UTC time

```cs
DateTime.TryParseExact("2022-04-17 14:46:31 UTC", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss 'UTC'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
DateTime utc = new DateTime(dt.Ticks,  DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/241885/7357322) you need to convert time zone name to time shift.

So to do it first we need to get table of time zone name to time zone shift. I copy it [from here](https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/214648-how-do-i-parse-date-w-time-zone) and convert to dictionary.

And the full algorithm is:

1. Find time zone name
2. Find it shift in dictionary
3. Replace time zone name with shift
4. Parse date string

---

```
var dateString = "2022-04-17 14:46:31 UTC";
var lastWhiteSpace = dateString.LastIndexOf(' ');
var timeZoneName = dateString.Substring(lastWhiteSpace+1);
var correctDate = dateString.Replace(timeZoneName, TimeZoneToShift[timeZoneName]);
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(correctDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz", null);
```

---

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> TimeZoneToShift = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"ACDT", "-10:30"},
    {"ACST", "-09:30"},
    {"ADT", "+03:00"},
    {"AEDT", "-11:00"},
    {"AEST", "-10:00"},
    {"AHDT", "+09:00"},
    {"AHST", "+10:00"},
    {"AST", "+04:00"},
    {"AT", "+02:00"},
    {"AWDT", "-09:00"},
    {"AWST", "-08:00"},
    {"BAT", "-03:00"},
    {"BDST", "-02:00"},
    {"BET", "+11:00"},
    {"BST", "+03:00"},
    {"BT", "-03:00"},
    {"BZT2", "+03:00"},
    {"CADT", "-10:30"},
    {"CAST", "-09:30"},
    {"CAT", "+10:00"},
    {"CCT", "-08:00"},
    {"CDT", "+05:00"},
    {"CED", "-02:00"},
    {"CET", "-01:00"},
    {"CST", "+06:00"},
    {"EAST", "-10:00"},
    {"EDT", "+04:00"},
    {"EED", "-03:00"},
    {"EET", "-02:00"},
    {"EEST", "-03:00"},
    {"EST", "+05:00"},
    {"FST", "-02:00"},
    {"FWT", "-01:00"},
    {"GMT", "+00:00"},
    {"GST", "-10:00"},
    {"HDT", "+09:00"},
    {"HST", "+10:00"},
    {"IDLE", "-12:00"},
    {"IDLW", "+12:00"},
    {"IST", "-05:30"},
    {"IT", "-03:30"},
    {"JST", "-09:00"},
    {"JT", "-07:00"},
    {"MDT", "+06:00"},
    {"MED", "-02:00"},
    {"MET", "-01:00"},
    {"MEST", "-02:00"},
    {"MEWT", "-01:00"},
    {"MST", "+07:00"},
    {"MT", "-08:00"},
    {"NDT", "+02:30"},
    {"NFT", "+03:30"},
    {"NT", "+11:00"},
    {"NST", "-06:30"},
    {"NZ", "-11:00"},
    {"NZST", "-12:00"},
    {"NZDT", "-13:00"},
    {"NZT", "-12:00"},
    {"PDT", "+07:00"},
    {"PST", "+08:00"},
    {"ROK", "-09:00"},
    {"SAD", "-10:00"},
    {"SAST", "-09:00"},
    {"SAT", "-09:00"},
    {"SDT", "-10:00"},
    {"SST", "-02:00"},
    {"SWT", "-01:00"},
    {"USZ3", "-04:00"},
    {"USZ4", "-05:00"},
    {"USZ5", "-06:00"},
    {"USZ6", "-07:00"},
    {"UT", "+00:00"},
    {"UTC", "+00:00"},
    {"UZ10", "-11:00"},
    {"WAT", "+01:00"},
    {"WET", "+00:00"},
    {"WST", "-08:00"},
    {"YDT", "+08:00"},
    {"YST", "+09:00"},
    {"ZP4", "-04:00"},
    {"ZP5", "-05:00"},
    {"ZP6", "-06:00"},
};
```