# Local Ambiguous DateTime to UTC

Tags: .net, datetime, timezone

Basically how do I convert a date string I know to be GMT to UTC where the date is ambiguous because it sits within the daylight savings switch over.

E.g. "29/10/2023 01:30:00" - in GMT where the clocks go back at 02:00 this could be the first time around or second time around - in C# if you `.ToUniversalTime()` on this `DateTime` object, it will always return 01:30.

Is there a way to tell this to UTC conversion 'hey this is the BST time' and the next time tell it it's the non BST time round?

As far as I can tell I can find the `TimeZoneInfo` object but it doesn't allow me to specify the non day light savings mode when using it to convert to UTC.

For context this is for a scheduling app where for example events occur every 15 minutes, the data comes from an external API which is giving me the date time as a string with the timezone in separate properties like 'GMT BST' and just 'GMT'.

Comment: [Neither UTC nor GMT ever change for Daylight Saving Time (DST). However, some of the countries that use GMT switch to different time zones during their DST period.](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/gmt-utc-time.html)

Comment: One solution would be to use TimeZoneInfo.IsAmbiguousTime and if that returns true, use the maximum value from TimeZoneInfo.GetAmbiguousTimeOffsets. I feel this is somewhat hacky in that some historical cases are not as simple. A proper solution would probably be going through the zone's adjustment rules, finding the relevant one and go from there. But even that may be non-deterministic. Maybe using NodaTime library could be a solution for you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse DateTime with time zone of form PST/CEST/UTC/etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241789/parse-datetime-with-time-zone-of-form-pst-cest-utc-etc)

Comment: To follow up on @Luuk's comment, there are no ambiguous times in UTC. See docs for [TimeZoneInfo.IsAmbiguousTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.isambiguoustime?view=net-7.0)

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek - Actually, `GetAmbiguousTimeOffsets` is exactly the correct approach.  It properly uses the adjustment rules under the hood, and does so in a performant manner.  See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your usage of "GMT" and "BST", I will assume you are giving an example of time in the United Kingdom, which uses GMT (UTC+0) for standard time, and BST (UTC+1) for daylight time.  Assuming you can tell from your input values which phase you are in, then you can indeed use that information when converting to UTC.

Here's an extension method that will work for any time zone:

```
public static DateTime ToUniversalTime(this DateTime dt, TimeZoneInfo tz, bool isDst)
{
    // If we're not dealing with unspecified kind, then the normal ToUniversalTime method is used.
    // Thus, the tz and isDst parameters are ignored.
    if (dt.Kind != DateTimeKind.Unspecified)
    {
        return dt.ToUniversalTime();
    }

    // Handle invalid values (impossible values in the local time zone, due to advancing local time).
    if (tz.IsInvalidTime(dt))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid local date and time for the specified time zone.");
    }

    // For ambiguous values, choose the offset for the indicated time zone and isDst flag.
    if (tz.IsAmbiguousTime(dt))
    {
        TimeSpan[] offsets = tz.GetAmbiguousTimeOffsets(dt);
        Array.Sort(offsets);
        TimeSpan offset = isDst ? offsets[1] : offsets[0];
        DateTimeOffset dto = new DateTimeOffset(dt, offset);
        return dto.UtcDateTime;
    }

    // Simple case
    return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dt, tz);
}
```

And using it with your example:

```
// For the UK, use "Europe/London" (or "GMT Standard Time" on Windows before .NET 6)
TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Europe/London");
DateTime london = new DateTime(2023, 10, 29, 1, 30, 0);

DateTime utcFromDst = london.ToUniversalTime(tz, true);
DateTime utcFromStd = london.ToUniversalTime(tz, false);

Console.WriteLine($"London: {london}");
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine($"UTC:    {utcFromDst} (assuming input was daylight time)");
Console.WriteLine($"UTC:    {utcFromStd} (assuming input was standard time)");
```

[See it working on .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/s0IK47).